# Cardinality of Hausdorff Space

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Here is a theorem which proof I don't understand (taken from R. Engelking, General Topology).

Theorem: For every Hausdorff space $X$ we have $|X| \le \operatorname{exp}\operatorname{exp} d(X)$. ($d(X)$ denotes the cardinality of the smallest dense subset of $X$)

Proof: Let $A$ be a dense subset of $X$ such that $|A| = d(X)$ and $\{ \mathcal B(x) \}_{x\in X}$ a neighbourhood system of $X$.
To prove the first inequality assign to every $x \in X$ the family $\mathcal A(x) = \{ U \cap A : U \in \mathcal B(x) \}$ of subsets of $A$. From the equality $\overline{U \cap A} = \overline{U}$ it follows that the intersection of the closures of all members of $\mathcal A(x)$ equals $\{ x \}$; hence $\mathcal A(x) \ne \mathcal A(y)$ for $x \ne y$. Since the number of all distinct families $\mathcal A(x)$ is not larger than $\operatorname{exp}\operatorname{exp}|A|$, we have $|X| \le \operatorname{exp}\operatorname{exp} d(X)$.

I don't understand why "the number of all distinct families $\mathcal A(x)$ is not larger than $\operatorname{exp}\operatorname{exp}|A|$", in my opinion, because of $\mathcal A(x) \subseteq A$, there could be no more distinct $\mathcal A(x)$ than subsets of $A$, and so the cardinality could be at most $\operatorname{exp} A$ (that of the powerset), and not twice exponential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathcal{A}(x)$ is not a subset of $A$. It is a set of subsets of $A$.